# How to get the count of a particular word from a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a file called `C:\User\abc\Desktop\Mtmlog.txt` and its contents are

```
1 Down@:01:46:44:902 Up@:04:08:00:233

1 Down@:02:40:44:908 Up@:03:08:00:293

1 Down@:05:50:44:978 Up@:06:08:00:263

1 Down@:09:45:44:103 Up@:10:08:00:283
```

There is an application where the Down and Up time is noted in that file.

To check continuity of application, I want a query to check if the Down count is equal to the Up count.
If the count is equal then it should echo `Yes` and if the count is different then echo `No`.

Comment: Does all lines contain Down and Up literals?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and easy to read. It counts the number of lines in which "Up" appears and sets the variable "UPS". Then it counts the number of lines in which "Down" appears and sets the variable "DOWNS".

```
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C "Up"   ^< yourfile') DO SET UPS=%%C
FOR /F %%C IN ('FIND /C "Down" ^< yourfile') DO SET DOWNS=%%C
if "%UPS%"=="%DOWNS%" echo Yes
if NOT "%UPS%"=="%DOWNS%" echo No
```

With your input file UPS gets set to 4 and DOWNS gets set to 4, so "Yes" is printed.

Comment: Hey Thanks man it works for me.But I have doubt on it. Script should check existance of Mtmlog.txt file first, if it exist then it should check for count of Up and Down. If file is not exist then output should be No. Also if file exist chech for Up and Down, if no Up and Down is there then also output should No.As of now if there is no Up and Down is present in file still above script will give output as Yes(count of Up=0=Down)

Answer (score 1):

This works here:

```
@echo off
findstr /v "^$" "C:\User\abc\Desktop\Mtmlog.txt" |findstr /v /i /r ".*down.*up.*" >nul && (echo No) || (echo yes)
```

This is another alternative:

```
@echo off
set var=0
findstr /v "^$" "C:\User\abc\Desktop\Mtmlog.txt" |findstr /v /i /r ".*down.*up.*" >nul && set var=1
if %var% equ 1 (echo No) else (echo yes)
```